# Using Clonezilla properly for backing up two physical disks, three OSes, to single USB drive

Tags: partitioning, backup, operating-systems, clonezilla

Never really used Clonezilla before and the guides I'm finding aren't exactly helpful for my setup. They are typically: 1 drive, 1 OS, to 1 backup drive.

I have two physical SSDs in my laptop. One of those SSDs has two partitions with an OS on each partition, and the other just has one. I'm wanting to back them up (obviously) such that if something happens to one OS, I can restore that OS (i.e., that partition) as opposed to all of them, or just one physical drive.

I have the bootable CZ USB, I'm just not sure what options are best for my situation and I'm not finding any decent explanations.

First question I have is these options:

- `device-image`
- `device-device`

Which is best for my situation and what does one do that the other doesn't?

Does `device-image` allow for you to mount the image in the OS to restore specific files? Not a requirement I have but not bad to have if it does so.

I'm just not sure what the benefit is of one over the other.

Comment: Use `device-image` and export mode as this will create a copy of your device (volume or entire disk) to a CloneZilla image on your USB. An alternative, but slightly overkill solution, is if you have access to an old PC with decent storage then you can install a FOSS solution called "FOG Project" which has a web GUI and uses the CloneZilla tools underneath and is bootable over the network using PXE. My work used to use this as our primary imaging solution for a few years until we moved to a Microsoft solution that worked with SCCM and the like.

Comment: And, yes, images can be opened ("mounted") using Linux to be able to access individual files to restore. Very useful.

Comment: Do what _Kinnectus_ said.

Comment: Is there any particular options i should make sure to use in expert mode? I've been running with clone by partition (and not disc), don't encrypt, don't check file system, check image... everything else as default. I did have to start over and noticed it was backing everything up in 4,000,000kb chunks.